# How to remove borders on Tkinter buttons & frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently building a simple app to encrypt files using AES encryption in python but the biggest downside of using Tkinter is the look of the UI. I did some research and found examples of what I want but do not know how to recreate it. ([Example](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13696193/49945232-67952580-feba-11e8-90c8-7dc31c5f7c67.gif))

My problem is that when I replace buttons with images (like the OP of the Reddit post said he did in order to have a decent looking UI) I end up with an ugly bar of grey. ([Image of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41p9s.png))

I also want to remove the same type of bar with frames so if you have the answer for specifically that it would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Support for for styles and themes has existed in `tkinter` for some time. A theme being a collection of styles for different widgets.

You can read more about style and themes [here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html).

To the best of my knowledge, the standard widgets to not support rounded corners. All widgets have rectangular shapes.

You *might* be able to create something like that using a `Canvas`, but it would be a significant amount of work.
A more relevant point is that it might confuse your users if you don't reproduce the way the standard controls work.

UI elements are standardized for the same reason the controls in a car are; once you know one of them you can use all of them.

Comment: Ttk has been around longer than tkinter 8.6.

Comment: @BryanOakley I misread; `theme_use` was originally targeted for Tk8.6. Fixed the text.